# Remove arrow from ammeter in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I'd like to remove the arrow from the ammeter symbol in circuitikz so that the symbol matches the one below. Is this possible?

[image: Ammeter symbol]

Comment: You could draw that with the ordinary Ti*k*Z stuff, like: `\node[draw,circle] (0,0) {A};`

Comment: or `\draw (0,0) to node[draw,circle] {A} (2,0);` ...

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Thanks Skillmon and Zarko, that seems to have done the job perfectly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Version 0.9.0 (2019-05-10), the generic meter type `rmeter` (round meter) has been added which allows you to set the internal symbol with the `t=...` option.

You might then use that to create a circuit consisting of a battery, one resistor, an ammeter, and a voltmeter to measure the current and voltage of that circuit like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,2)   to[battery]       (0,0)
      (0,2)   --                (2,2)
      (2,2)   to[R=\(R_1\)]     (2,0)
      (2,2)   --                (4,2)
      (4,2)   to[rmeter, t=V]   (4,0)
      (4,0)   --                (2,0)
      (2,0)   to[rmeter, t=A]   (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Which should produce the following output:
[image: The example circuit described, an inner loop with a battery, resistor, and ammeter, with an outer loop consisting of the battery, a voltmeter, and ammeter.]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update an answer to such an ancient question. It's unlikely that I'll ever find a use for this, but I hope your answer helps anyone else who stumbles across this question :-)

Comment: The original accepted answer was very useful to me at the time, so when I was reading the documentation yesterday and saw this was now an option I couldn't help but want to update it!

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what Skillmon and Zarko stated, add `fill=white` when using it in a circuit to prevent a line running through it. Using the example from https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/09/02/tikz-series-pt4.html

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[battery] (0,4)
  to[ammeter] (4,4) -- (4,0)
  to[lamp] (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

One would have to change the `ammeter` to:

```
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) to[battery] (0,4)
  to node[draw,circle,fill=white] {A} (4,4) -- (4,0)
  to[lamp] (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use esource and then just put a node at the esource location. There is probably a better way than manually putting the location.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
   (0,0)to[short,*-*] (2,0)
          to[short,*-*] (3,0)
          to[esource,*-*] (3,2)  
          to[short,*-*] (2,2)
          to[short,*-*] (0,2)
    (0,0) to[eC,invert,l=$C$,*-*] (0,2)
    (2,0) to[R, l=$R_1$,*-*] (2,2)
    (3,1) node {$V$};
\end{circuitikz}
```